# Checkboxes instead of drop down list in PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have this working code below, but i'd like to change it from drop down list to checkboxes, so multiple options can be selected and passed for further action instead of just one that the drop down list allows.
I'm fairy new to PHP and have done tons of searching on this without any success. Any help is much appreciated.

```
    $l = $_POST['LT'];
    $pals = '';

    $r = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT pal_num FROM pl_tab WHERE lt_num='$l'");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
    {
        $pals .= '<option>'.$row['pal_num'].'</option>';

    }

    if($pal == '')
        echo '';
    else 
    echo '<form name="get_pal" action="post.php" method="POST">';
    echo '<select name="pal_numb"><option>Select Pal</option>'.$pals.'</select>';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="post" value="Go!">';
    echo '</form>';
```

Comment: you can also do multiselect in drop down list, is there specific reason you need checkbox?

Comment: echo '<select name="pal_numb" multiple><option>Select Pal</option>'.$pals.'</select>';

Comment: Well, you have to replace the select box you code by coding those check boxes. That is not really anything we can help with, since there is no problem in that. Unless you want others to do your work...

Comment: if it is multiple checkboxes, and using pure vanilla HTML then you need to echo multiple <input> where type="checkbox"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### With Checkbox

```
<?php
    $l = $_POST['LT'];
    $pals = '';

    $r = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT pal_num FROM pl_tab WHERE lt_num='$l'");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
    {
        $pals .= '<input type="checkbox" name="pal_numb[]" value="'.$row['pal_num'].'">'.$row['pal_num'].'<br>';
    }

    if($pal == '')
        echo '';
    else
    echo '<form name="get_pal" action="post.php" method="POST">';
    echo $pals;
    echo '<input type="submit" name="post" value="Go!">';
    echo '</form>';
?>
```

#### With Select Multiple

Append `multiple` to `select` like below as @sudhakar said

```
 echo '<select name="pal_numb" multiple><option>Select Pal</option>'.$pals.'</select>';
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. It took a couple mins for you, i couldn't figure it out for hours lol

Answer (score 1):

```
$l = $_POST['LT'];
$pals = '';

$r = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT pal_num FROM pl_tab WHERE lt_num='$l'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
{
   $pals .= '<br /><input type="checkbox" name="pal_numb" value="'.$row['pal_num'].'">'.$row['pal_num'];

}

if($pal == '')
    echo '';
else 
echo '<form name="get_pal" action="post.php" method="POST">';
echo $pals;
echo '<input type="submit" name="post" value="Go!">';
echo '</form>';
```

use this code